# Addition of element in a list of record (OCaml)

Tags: list, ocaml, record

I have a list of record :

```
list_clients = [{name = "c6"; number = 9}; {name = "c12"; number = 3}; {name = "c17"; number = 6};]
```

I would like to simply make the sum of all the "number" of each record.

What is the best way? I'm quite beginner with OCaml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a fold:

```
List.fold_left (fun acc nxt -> nxt.number+acc) 0 list_clients
```

This takes every element in the list, grabs said element's 'number' field, and adds it to the total thus far, passing along the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It's exactly what I was trying to reproduce.

Answer (score 3):

A bit more explanation about Charles Marsh's answer.

[`List.fold_left : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALfold_left) takes a function `f`, an element `a` and a list `[b1; b2; ...; bn]` and computes `f (... (f (f a b1) b2) ...) bn`. It allows you you to easily compute the sum of the elements of a list: `List.fold_left (+) 0 l`, its maximum element: `List.fold_left max (List.hd l) l` or anything where you need to go through every element of the list, aggregating it with the previous result.